# PHP namespace class not found when Use statement is in included fle

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

My problem seems to be around where I am declaring my classes.  If I have everything in one .php file, the autoload, the Use declarations and my script that uses those classes within the same file it all works correctly.  However, when I have my  "Use" statements in a separate required file, I get class not found errors.  I eventually want to instantiate class objects in a function, but I can't get past this issue.

Comment: OK, I will post code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

My fault - I needed to have the Use statements at the top of every included file.  Right there in the documenation, somehow I missed it.